# How can I make an element visible on hovering an element from another section?

Tags: css, hover, scss-lint

HTML

```
<nb-sidebar class="menu-sidebar>
  <nb-menu class="sidebar-menu">
     <ul class="menu-items">
        <li class="menu-item ng-tns-c140-0 ng-star-inserted" >
          <a class="ng-tns-c140-0 ng-star-inserted active" ng-reflect-router-link="/pages/dashboard"   title="Dashboard" href="/pages/dashboard">
        </li>
     </ul>
  </nb-menu>
</nb-sidebar>

<div class="content">
  <router-outlet>
    <div class="text">Message</div>
  </router-outlet>
</div>
```

Make `router-outlet` visible when I hover on `li`.

I tried like this

```
router-outlet {
  display: none;
}

nb-sidebar li:hover + .content router-outlet {
     display: block;
}
```

I want to do it with css/scss only. I want `router-outlet` to be visible when I hover on `li`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your example because the `.content router-outlet` element isn't a direct sibling of the `li` element the Adjacent Sibling Combinator won't work (see [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_combinator) for details)

However there's a couple of ways of doing this. The first uses the `:has()` [pseudo class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has) which is neat as it doesn't need any javascript but isn't currently supported on all browsers.  There's a [nice introduction](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OGJvhpoE8b4) to this from Kevin Powell. Also [caniuse.com](https://caniuse.com/?search=%3Ahas) is a good resource to check for browser compatibility.

Note: I've added some text on your html to give you something to hover over.

```css
router-outlet {
  display: none;
}

/* added this */
nb-sidebar:has(li:hover) + .content router-outlet {
     display: block;
}
```

```html
<nb-sidebar class="menu-sidebar>
  <nb-menu class="sidebar-menu">
     <ul class="menu-items">
        <li class="menu-item ng-tns-c140-0 ng-star-inserted" >
          <a class="ng-tns-c140-0 ng-star-inserted active" ng-reflect-router-link="/pages/dashboard"   title="Dashboard" href="/pages/dashboard">This is the anchor inside the li</a>
        </li>
     </ul>
  </nb-menu>
</nb-sidebar>

<div class="content">
  <router-outlet>
    <div class="text">Message</div>
  </router-outlet>
</div>
```

The more generally supported way would be to use javascript which detects you mousing over the element then adding and removing a class to override the `display: none` rule as follows. The code below should be self-evident but if you have any questions just pop a comment below and I'll elaborate.

```js
window.onload = () => {
  const elem = document.querySelector('.menu-item');
  elem.addEventListener('mouseover', (e) => {
    document.querySelector('.content router-outlet').classList.add('display-block');
  });

  elem.addEventListener('mouseout', (e) => {
    document.querySelector('.content router-outlet').classList.remove('display-block');
  });
}
```

```css
router-outlet {
  display: none;
}

.display-block {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<nb-sidebar class="menu-sidebar>
  <nb-menu class=" sidebar-menu ">
     <ul class="menu-items ">
        <li class="menu-item ng-tns-c140-0 ng-star-inserted " >
          <a class="ng-tns-c140-0 ng-star-inserted active " ng-reflect-router-link="/pages/dashboard "   title="Dashboard " href="/pages/dashboard ">This is the anchor inside the li</a>
        </li>
     </ul>
  </nb-menu>
</nb-sidebar>

<div class="content ">
  <router-outlet>
    <div class="text ">Message</div>
  </router-outlet>
</div>
```

Comment: I keep forgetting about `:has()`, nice solution

Comment: My pleasure dude. Have a truly great day :-D

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery hover() method:

```css
p {
  background: orange
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("p").hover(function(){
    $('h1').css("display", "block");
    }, function(){
    $('h1').css("display", "none");
  });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<p>Hover the mouse pointer over this paragraph.</p>
<h1>Title</h1>

</body>
</html>
```

In your code it would be:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("li").hover(function(){
    $('.router-outlet').css("display", "block");}, function(){
   $('.router-outlet').css("display", "none");});
  });
```